# Python 2 - add method to imported object

Tags: python, overriding, python-2.6

Using Python 2.6, which does not have `logging.Logger.getChild(name)` implemented yet, how can I backport this function inside an existing program that relies on it?

The code of the function can be basically reduced to one line, which I try to put into the Logger class as lambda function like this at the top of my program:

```
import sys, logging
if sys.version_info <= (2, 6):
    logging.Logger.getChild = lambda self, suffix:\
        self.manager.getLogger('.'.join((self.name, suffix)) if self.root is not self else suffix)
```

But Travis-CI still tells me that it did not work with lots of errors like that one:

```
self.logger = logger.getChild('Browser')
E   AttributeError: Logger instance has no attribute 'getChild'
```

where the global variable `logger` gets initialized before that with:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

What is my error here and how can I tune my code to support Python 2.6 without leaving out the `getChild(name)` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version check will fail if `sys.version_info` returns (as in my test) a tuple with more than 2 elements:

```
>>> sys.version_info
(2, 6, 6, 'final', 0)
>>> sys.version_info <= (2, 6)
False
```

resulting in your back port never being defined. One fix would be to restrict the comparison to the first two elements:

```
if sys.version_info[:2] <= (2, 6):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed that worked. Probably because of the micro version being >0.